# Linq extension methods - how to include not loaded objects?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have something like this:

```
var threads = _forumsDb.ForumsAccounts
.Where(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
.SelectMany(u => u.Threads);
```

But those thread entities have posts entities associated with them, which are not loaded due to lazy loading. If i do something like this:

```
var threads = _forumsDb.ForumsAccounts
.Include("Posts")
.Where(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
.SelectMany(u => u.Threads);
```

It's apparently not working, and those thread entities still have null Posts entities. How can i do it correctly?

Comment: how do you setup the relation between ForumsAccount and Posts, does Include(x => x.Posts) compile ?

Comment: I cannot do lambda expression inside of include, can only input strings, and as for my setup of tables, the ForumsAccount includes icollection of threads and icollection of posts, and thread entity includes icollection of posts.

Comment: if you have a using System.Data.Entity, the fact you can't use lambda could mean that, from a EF point of view, the relation is not correctly set.

Comment: No, i just checked the working includes, and those do not allow lambda either.

Comment: If you use EF >= 4.1 with `DbContext` (and you must use this because your question has an `ef-code-first` tag), the `Include` which takes a lambda expression must work. You just need `using System.Data.Entity;` for your code file as @tschmit007 already indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply `Include` for properties in a projection (`Select` or `SelectMany`). You need to extend the projection to include the posts as an additional property:

```
var threads = _forumsDb.ForumsAccounts
    .Where(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
    .SelectMany(u => new
    {
        Threads = u.Threads,
        ThreadPosts = u.Threads.Select(t => t.Posts)
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(a => a.Threads)
    .ToList();
```

If the relationship between `Thread` and `Post` is one-to-many EF will fill the `Posts` collection of the threads.

The query would be much easier though if you have an inverse `ForumAccount` property on the `Thread` entity:

```
var threads = _forumsDb.Threads
    .Include("Posts")
    .Where(t => t.ForumAccount.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
    .ToList();
```

In this case eager loading with `Include` will work.

Comment: Oh well, this was entertaining, thank you. And the second approach is surely easier to implement, it works, i didn't think about doing it like that, apparently had too much programming today. :) Thank you once again.